# C# Update Uri String

Tags: c#, string, list, uri

I got this code when a list item is selected the "teamsite" string changes.
but how can i get the Uri addept to the teamsite string, i want `new Uri(teamsite)` to get the same value as the teamsite string is when i have chosen a item from the list
so when i chose the `Elite Junioren` item, the `new Uri(teamsite)` equals `"http://www.test2.com"` instead of `"http://www.test.com"`

```
string teamsite = "http://www.test.com";

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        new Uri(teamsite),
}

private void List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  string teamsitecheck = (string)List.SelectedItem;
  if (teamsitecheck == "Elite Junioren")
  {
  teamsite = "http://www.test2.com";
  }
  else if (teamsitecheck == "Elite Aspiranten")
  {
  teamsite = "http://www.test3.com";
  }
}
```

i hope i have explained it well enough, ask me for more explenation if it is needed!

(sorry for my bad grammer)

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do or what the problem is.  the code in OnNavigatedTo clearly will not compile.

Comment: I guess this is a web browser control. Have you tried redirecting the control to the new Uri?

Comment: sorry i don't know how you do that i am verry new to C# and i got this protected overrride from somebody else.

Comment: @can poyrazoğlu how do you do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking (I don't even know if this is Silverlight, WPF, WinForm, etc.).

However, instead of explicitly mapping in your code, how about setting the value of the ListItem (value is different from Text, but defaults to it if not specified) to the appropriate teamsite name, so that in your code you can do:

```
teamsite = (Uri) List.SelectedItem.Value;
```

Comment: i don't know how to give the item a value what has to be a url

Comment: value is of type object, so it can be anything. How are you loading the list? Note that in your example, teamsite is of type string not Uri, that's why I had it as string not Uri.